# Critical point analysis for $x'=y,y'=x^2-y-\epsilon$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I'm going through question 5 the past exam [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-034-honors-differential-equations-spring-2009/exams/MIT18_034s09_exam04_pfinal.pdf). For starters, I'm trying to find and classify the critical points of the system
$$\begin{align} x'&=y, \\ y'&=x^2-y-\epsilon.  \end{align}$$ I've found that:

- The system has no critical points if $\epsilon<0$.
- The system has a critical point at $(0,0)$ if $\epsilon=0$.
- The system has two critical points at $(\pm \sqrt{\epsilon},0)$ if $\epsilon>0$.

I've managed to classify the critical points, except for the following boundary cases:

1. $(0,0)$ when $\epsilon=0$, as the linearized system has zero determinant.
2. $(-\sqrt{\epsilon},0) $ when $\epsilon=1/64$, which falls on the parabola in the [trace-det critical point picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duPPi.png).

All I have is computer generated trajectories, which make me suspect that $(0,0)$ is a saddle. I'd like to know whether my list of boundary cases is corret, and within the list, what is the type of the critical points.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is a theorem which says so long as the critical (or equilibrium) point is not a center then the nature of this critical point in the system $x',y'$, is the same as that point  in the linearization i.e,

$$\tilde{x}' = p_x(x_0,y_0) \cdot x + p_y(x_0,y_0)  \cdot y$$

$$ \tilde{y}' = q_x(x_0,y_0) \cdot x + q_y(x_0,y_0) \cdot y$$

where $x' = p(x,y)$ and $y' = q(x,y)$. Now you have a linear system. Find the associated matrix to this system, compute it's eigenvalues and use the Painleve Analysis.

$\textbf{Update}$: My professor refereed to it as Painless analysis, but it seems to also be reference as *linearization technique for equilibrium point analysis*. In any case, here are two links [1](http://math.colgate.edu/~wweckesser/math312Spring05/handouts/Linearization.pdf),[2](http://kaharris.org/teaching/216/Lectures/lec28/lec28.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Solving $x' = 0 = y'$, we get
\begin{aligned}
x^2 &= \epsilon \\
y &= 0 \, .
\end{aligned}
Therefore, no critical point (or equilibrium point) is obtained with $\epsilon < 0$.

The origin is the only critical point when $\epsilon = 0$. One eigenvalue of the flow's Jacobian matrix at $(0,0)$ is $-1$, the other is zero. Therefore, this critical point is [non hyperbolic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_equilibrium_point). Below is the phase plane, which may confirm that the origin is a saddle-point:

[image: $\epsilon = 0$]

When $\epsilon > 0$, two critical points $(\pm\sqrt{\epsilon},0)$ arise. Let us compute the eigenvalues of the flow's Jacobian matrix at the critical points. Depending on the sign of the characteristic polynomial's determinant $\Delta^\pm = 1\pm 8\sqrt{\epsilon}$, the eigenvalues of the flow's Jacobian matrix at the critical points may be complex conjugate or real.

- if $0 < \epsilon < 1/64$, the determinant $\Delta^\pm$ at both critical points is positive. Therefore, all four eigenvalues $-\frac{1}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}\pm 2\sqrt{\epsilon}}$ are real. At the critical point $(-\sqrt{\epsilon},0)$, both eigenvalues are negative, whereas at the critical point $(\sqrt{\epsilon},0)$, the eigenvalues have opposite signs.
- if $\epsilon = 1/64$, the determinant $\Delta^\pm$ is zero at the critical point $(-\sqrt{\epsilon},0)$. The double eigenvalue is negative. At the critical point $(\sqrt{\epsilon},0)$, the determinant $\Delta^\pm$ is positive, and the eigenvalues still have opposite signs.
- if $\epsilon > 1/64$, the determinant $\Delta^\pm$ is negative at the critical point $(-\sqrt{\epsilon},0)$. The eigenvalues are complex conjugates with negative real part. At the critical point $(\sqrt{\epsilon},0)$, the determinant $\Delta^\pm$ is positive, and the eigenvalues still have opposite signs.

In all these cases, all eigenvalues have nonzero real part, so that according to the Hartman-Grobman theorem, the system will behave similarly to the linearized system in the vicinity of critical points. Below is the phase plane in the case $\epsilon = 1$:

[image: $\epsilon = 1$]

Answer (score 1):

1. In the first case the Jacobian matrix is
   $$
   \left(\begin{array}{rr}
   0&1\\0&-1
   \end{array}\right).
   $$
   As one of its eigenvalues is $0$, the [Hartman-Grobman theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartman%E2%80%93Grobman_theorem) is not applicable to this case, thus, we can say nothing about the structure of the critical point of the nonlinear system. The phase portrait of this system is
   [image]
   (the blue trajectories are stable, the red trajectories are unstable).
   We can see here that this is some kind of [Saddle-sink](http://staff.www.ltu.se/~larserik/applmath/chap9en/part7.html).
2. In the second case the Jacobian matrix is equal to 
   $$
   \left(\begin{array}{rr}
   0&1\\-\frac14&-1
   \end{array}\right),
   $$
   its eigenvalues are $(-\frac12,-\frac12)$. As the eigenvalues have nonzero real part, the Hartman-Grobman theorem is applicable; hence, according to the diagram, this critical point is (homeomorphic to) a degenerate sink.